# Python decorators in classes Error

Tags: python, python-decorators

```
class A(object):
    def wrapped(self, func):
        func.string = self.get_something()
        return func

    def get_something(self):
        return "something"

    @wrapped
    def main(self):
        print self.main.string
a = A()
a.main()
```

> TypeError: wrapped() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: `wrapped` is being called before the class even exists... so there are no instances (obviously) and therefore nothing that could be considered `self`...  What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to implicate static variables in main. So , the variables will be assigned when I call the main function rather than A ()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wrapped()` is called at the definition of `main()`.  When it is called, it is not given `self`, because there is no instance of `A` that can be given to `wrapped()`.  To do what you want, don't use decorators.  Instead, define an `__init__()` method that assigns the right attributes.  I don't know why you want it to be an attribute of `self.main()`, however.  Generally it is not a good idea to add attributes to functions.  You already have a class; use it.  Just define `self.string` instead of `self.main.string`.

Comment: I want to implicate static variables in main () .

Comment: In that case, define them within `main()`.